# Как обновить данные в БД, если запись уже существует, а если нет, то создать?

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework-core, update

У меня есть GET запрос который получает данные в формате json и записывает их в БД. Мне нужно что бы те данные, которые уже есть в таблице обновлялись, а те которых нет добавлялись. У меня в базе есть поле shipmentId, оно всегда остается неизменным, я предполагаю что можно его как то использовать, но не понимаю как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо)

```
static async Task<OtvetGet> GetRequest(string url, ZaprosGet zapros)
        {
            OtvetContext context = new OtvetContext();

            string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(zapros);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

            var customerJsonString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var ans = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OtvetGet>(custome‌​rJsonString);

            context.Otvets.Add(ans);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return ans;

        }
```

Модель OtvetGet

```
public class OtvetGet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("success")]
        public int success { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("meta")]
        public Meta? meta { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("data")]

        public Data? data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? fromProxy { get; set; }
        public string? requestId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shipments")]
        public List<Shipment> shipments { get; set; } = new List<Shipment>();
    }

    public class Shipment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? orderCode { get; set; }
        public string? status { get; set; }
        public string? shipmentId { get; set; }
        public string? confirmedTimeLimit { get; set; }
        public string? packingTimeLimit { get; set; }
        public string? shippingTimeLimit { get; set; }
        public string? shipmentDateFrom { get; set; }
        public string? shipmentDateTo { get; set; }
        public string? deliveryId { get; set; }
        public bool shipmentDateShift { get; set; }
        public bool shipmentIsChangeable { get; set; }
        public string? customerFullName { get; set; }
        public string? customerAddress { get; set; }
        public string? shippingPoint { get; set; }
        public string? creationDate { get; set; }
        public string? deliveryDate { get; set; }
        public string? deliveryDateFrom { get; set; }
        public string? deliveryDateTo { get; set; }
        //[JsonProperty("items")]
        public List<Item> items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
        public string? deliveryMethodId { get; set; }
        public string? serviceScheme { get; set; }
        public string? customer { get; set; }
        public int depositedAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? itemIndex { get; set; }
        public string? status { get; set; }
        public string? subStatus { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public int finalPrice { get; set; }
        public List<Discount> discounts { get; set; } = new List<Discount>();
        [NotMapped]
        public string[]? priceAdjustments { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string? offerId { get; set; }
        public string? goodsId { get; set; }
        public string? digitalMark { get; set; }
        public Goodsdata? goodsData { get; set; }
        public List<Event> events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();
        public string? boxIndex { get; set; }
    }

    public class Goodsdata
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public bool isDelivery { get; set; }
        public string? categoryName { get; set; }
        public bool isDigitalMarkRequired { get; set; }
    }

    public class Discount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? discountType { get; set; }
        public string? discountDescription { get; set; }
        public int discountAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? eventDate { get; set; }
        public string? eventName { get; set; }
        public string? eventValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Ну сделайте запрос в базу по `shipmentId`, если есть, то обновляйте, если нет, то добавляйте, делов то.

Comment: `HttpClient client = new HttpClient()` - HttpClient не предназначен для создания на каждый запрос, вынесите его во статичное поле и создавайте там однократно. Иначе приложение будет расходовать много сетевых ресурсов у компа. Об этом написано даже в документации по HttpClient - _[HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient#examples)_

Comment: В этом и вопрос, я не особо представляю как это написать. Можете пожалуйста написать пример кода с shipmentId? И мне нужно желательно не SQL запросом это делать, а в формате кода C#, такое возможно?

Comment: Что такое `OtvetContext`, какой тип базы данных и ORM и версия какая?

Comment: Тип базы mssql, как понять какая версия ORM? (заранее извиняюсь, я новичок просто)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM

Comment: У меня стоит EntityFrameworkCore версия 7.02

Comment: Вот теперь понятнее. Я сам по EF Core не шарю, но думаю, найдутся те, кто подскажет, как это на базе EF реализовать. Кстати, с учетом того что у вас .NET 7, использование Newtonsoft.Json выглядит странным, так как для этой версии дотнета он считается устаревшим, используйте встроенный в дотнет System.Text.Json.

Comment: `var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;` это ошибка, должно быть `var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);`, метод же асинхронный. Вообще использовать `.Result` для незавершенных `Task` - всегда ошибка.

Comment: Ух, одновременно используется и System.Text.Json, и Newtonsoft.Json, а ещё .Result. Про HttpClient уже сказали.

Comment: Покажите код типа `OtvetGet`.

Comment: Он очень большой, не помещается в комментарий(

Comment: Не надо комментарий! Редактируйте вопрос. Вообще можно полностью удалить показанный код. Оставить лишь код определения сущностей, код DbContext'а, и примерный код, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Понял, секунду)

Comment: Вы приняли ответ. Значит _правильное_ решение с использованием Entity Framework вам не нужно? OK, я умываю руки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляю к предыдущему ответу. В C# вы можете использовать библиотеку, такую как Newtonsoft.Json, для анализа данных JSON и извлечения свойств, которые вы хотите вставить в таблицу. Затем вы можете использовать ADO.NET (например, SqlCommand и SqlParameter) для создания и выполнения инструкции INSERT INTO с извлеченными свойствами в качестве значений. Вот пример:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    string property1 = jsonData["property1"].Value<string>();
    string property2 = jsonData["property2"].Value<string>();
    string property3 = jsonData["property3"].Value<string>();

    string query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (@value1, @value2, @value3)";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", property1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", property2);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", property3);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Вам нужно будет заменить connectionString на вашу фактическую строку подключения к базе данных, а jsonString на данные json, которые вы хотите вставить.

Comment: Для вставки данных из json в БД MS SQL

Comment: Ответы можно редактировать. Вы можете объединить всю информацию в одном ответе. А лишнее удалить.

Comment: Автор использует десериализацию. Накой ему JObject? Автор использует Entity Framework. Накой ему сырой ADO.NET? Тем более с порочным AddWithValue.

Comment: Alexander Petrov занимайтесь тем что требует этот сайт, а не критикуйте ответы и решения других людей

Comment: По правилам этого сайта критиковать ответы можно и нужно. Оба ваши сообщения не являются правильным ответом.

Comment: Alexander Petrov молодец продолжай дальше!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать shipmentId как ключ для обновления или вставки данных в БД. Вам нужно использовать инструкцию SQL UPSERT (update или insert) для выполнения этой операции.

Например, если вы используете SQLite, вы можете использовать следующий запрос:

INSERT INTO table_name (shipmentId, column1, column2, ...)
VALUES (:shipmentId, :value1, :value2, ...)
ON CONFLICT (shipmentId)
DO UPDATE SET column1 = :value1, column2 = :value2, ...;

Если вы используете MySQL, вам нужно использовать следующий запрос:

INSERT INTO table_name (shipmentId, column1, column2, ...)
VALUES (:shipmentId, :value1, :value2, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
column1 = VALUES(column1), column2 = VALUES(column2), ...;

Здесь, shipmentId является ключом для обновления или вставки данных. Вместо использования конкретных значений, вы можете использовать параметры запроса, чтобы динамически передавать значения из json в запрос.

Обратите внимание, что это только общий пример, и использование, синтаксис и методы могут отличаться в зависимости от типа базы данных, которую вы используете. Поэтому, убедитесь, что вы используете синтаксис, соответствующий вашей базе данных.

Comment: А если у меня база mssql то какой синтаксис следует использовать? И можно ли выполнить эту задачу не используя SQL синтаксис (INSERT INTO и тд)?

Comment: Для вставки данных из json в БД MS SQL вы можете использовать синтаксис T-SQL с командой INSERT INTO. Синтаксис будет примерно таким: `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (json_data->'$.property1', json_data->'$.property2', json_data->'$.property3')`. Где table_name - имя таблицы, в которую вы хотите вставить данные, json_data - имя переменной, которая содержит json-данные, а property1, property2, property3 - свойства в json, которые вы хотите вставить в соответствующие столбцы.

Comment: Понял, а все эти команды нужно написать как бы в переменную? Или куда их вставлять?

Comment: @КириллМягчилов если вы приняли ответ как правильный, то какие могут быть вопросы? Если непонятно как использовать ответ, надо сначала разобраться, а потом принимать.

Comment: Я дурак, нажал, а потом подумал

Comment: @КириллМягчилов оно отжимается назад свободно, если что)

Comment: @aepot ты видимо здесь отслеживать что надо делать а что не надо, а не помощь людям)))

Comment: Ну зайди в профиль, глянь ответы вместо того чтобы глупости писать.

Comment: @aepot еще мне остался по профилям шариться как вы)) как будто мне делать нечего. Спасибо лучше уж выделю свое свободное время другим в помощи.